# Visual Studio Build Error on Visual Studio 2022, With Xamarin.Android.framework 12.2.0.4

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(5,5): Error XALNK7004: Mono.ArgumentNullOrEmptyException: Argument null or empty
> Parameter name: name
> at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckName (System.String name) [0x0001d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/ModuleDefinition.cs:1223
> at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.GetType (System.String namespace, System.String name) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/ModuleDefinition.cs:706
> at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.GetTypeDefinition (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:159
> at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.GetType (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, Mono.Cecil.TypeReference reference) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:133
> at Mono.Cecil.MetadataResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x0005e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/MetadataResolver.cs:116
> at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/ModuleDefinition.cs:762
> at Mono.Cecil.TypeReference.Resolve () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/cecil/Mono.Cecil/TypeReference.cs:280
> at Mono.Linker.Steps.SweepStep.UpdateForwardedTypesScope (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00029] in :0
> at Mono.Linker.Steps.SweepStep.SweepAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00118] in :0
> at Mono.Linker.Steps.SweepStep.ProcessAssemblyAction (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00080] in :0
> at Mono.Linker.Steps.SweepStep.Process () [0x0004a] in :0
> at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00010] in :0
> at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context, Mono.Linker.Steps.IStep step) [0x0000d] in :0
> at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x0000f] in :0
> at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Run (Mono.Linker.Pipeline pipeline, Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0
> at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process (MonoDroid.Tuner.LinkerOptions options, Mono.Linker.ILogger logger, Mono.Linker.LinkContext& context) [0x00071] in :0
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute (Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver res) [0x0018f] in :0
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask () [0x0001b] in :0
> at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:17  (XALNK7004) (WoWonder)

Comment: Whats the question here exactly?

Comment: The linker is known to break in certain cases, so please send feedback to Microsoft, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.